# How do I change my Django app index page url from http://127.0.0.1:8000/qa/ to http://127.0.0.1:8000/?

Tags: django

I created my Django app, qa, under a project as described in many tutorials. But I now want my index page to be `mysite.com` not `mysite.com/qa`. Similarly, I would like to remove the `/qa/` from all the urls that are currently preceded with `/qa/` because of the include of qa urls.py in my project urls.py. What's the easiest way to make that change in a Django project? My current directory structure is:

```
/project
    /project
        urls.py
        /static
            project.css
            project.js
        /templates
            base.html    
    /qa
        forms.py
        models.py
        urls.py
        views.py
        /templates
            /qa
                /templates
        /templatetags
    /registration
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably having something like that right now:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    [...]    
    url(r'^qa/', include('qa.urls')),
    [...]
)
```

Just update it like that:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    [...]
    url(r'^/', include('qa.urls')),
    [...]
)
```

You'll find more on this topic here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs

Comment: Thanks. Yes that's exactly what I have and I tried your suggestion myself before posting my question. http://127.0.0.1:8000/qa/ works if my url pattern is "url(r'^qa/', include('qa.urls'))," but http://127.0.0.1:8000/ does not work if I change my url pattern to "url(r'^/', include('qa.urls')),"

Comment: It should just be `r''`.

Comment: SOLVED with: url(r'', include('qa.urls')),